# Firebase indexOn for a nested property

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My database structure is this:

```
 {
   "Products" : {
     "0100251633" : {
       "codes" : {
         "Call" : "000156",
         "EAN13" : "7898613211028"
       },
       "productid" : "0100251633",
       "nmproduct" : "BRW 12 COLOR HYDROGRAPHIC PEN",
       "quantity" : 0,
       "stativo" : "S",
       "url" : "SemUrl"
     }
   }
 }
```

I need to sort(index) my database by the "Call" code.

The rule that works (ordered by description) is this one:

```
 {
   "rules": {
     ".read": "auth.uid != null",
     ".write": "auth.uid != null",
       "Products":{
         ".indexOn": ["nmproduct","codes","Call"]
       }
   }
 }
```

But I need to sort by calling code. I'm trying this way because this is how I understand it:

```
 {
   "rules": {
     ".read": "auth.uid != null",
     ".write": "auth.uid != null",
       "Products":{
         "Codes":{
             ".indexOn": ["Call"]
         }
       }
   }
 }
```

It's not working, I'm getting the return below:

```
 raise HTTPError(e, request_object.text)
 requests.exceptions.HTTPError: [Errno 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url:           https://inventarioshop-8318f-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/Produtos.json?     auth=65465465465465465465465465&orderBy=%22Chamada%22] {
    "error" : "Index not defined, add \".indexOn\": \"Call\", for path \"/Products\", to the rules"
  }
```

I would really appreciate your help to understand and be able to explain to other people as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To index a nested property under a node, you need to specify the path to that property in the index definition.

So for your call code that'd be:

```
"Products":{
  ".indexOn": ["nmproduct","codes/Call"]
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot!
I was doing it this way only in python code, the correct thing is to do the same in mos, in the rules and in the code of your language.

With your help I did this:
products = db.child("Products").order_by_child("codes/Call").get(token='1111111112222222222')

This was what I was doing:

products = db.child("Products").order_by_child("Call").get(token='1111111112222222222')

Thank you very much!